# Selecting data point and the one preceding it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query pairs of messages associated with a particular `offer_id`. 
Using subquery:

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT M.offer_id
FROM quotes_site.messages M
where (regexp_substr (REPLACE(M.body, ' ', ''), '[0][0-9]{8,12}') != '') and (M.body NOT iLIKE '%agreement%' AND M.author_type = 'User') AND
M.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-03' AND '2016-02-03'
)
```

And then by joining X with the original table I get the thread that is associated with this `id` (for all available `author_type`)

```
SELECT MSG.body, MSG.offer_id, MSG.author_type
FROM quotes_site.messages MSG
INNER JOIN X
ON MSG.offer_id = X.offer_id
ORDER BY MSG.offer_id, MSG.created_at
```

The question is how do I get the table MSG to contain messages I found in subquery and ONLY the one that precedes it in chronological order (but for the same `offer_id`)

Comment: Add order by created_at desc, then do LIMIT/TOP/FETCH FIRST 2 rows.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me only the first/last two msgs? The thing is message that I need to use as a point of reference could have been created at any point

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully enough - you mean two rows for each offer_id?

Comment: Yes, so the one that corresponds to the WHERE criteria and the other one  that was created before it

Comment: Can you show some sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY` clause so as to enumerate messages belonging to the same `offer_id` group:

```
WITH M AS (
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY offer_id 
                             ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM quotes_site.messages 
) X AS (
   SELECT M.offer_id, M.rn              
   FROM M
   WHERE (regexp_substr (REPLACE(M.body, ' ', ''), '[0][0-9]{8,12}') != '') 
         AND (M.body NOT iLIKE '%agreement%' AND M.author_type = 'User') 
         AND (M.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-03' AND '2016-02-03')
)
SELECT M.body, M.offer_id, M.author_type
FROM M
INNER JOIN X ON MSG.offer_id = X.offer_id AND M.rn BETWEEN X.rn AND x.rn - 1
ORDER BY M.offer_id, M.created_at
```